# Using dlopen() and dlsym() to get an object out of .so library in C++

Tags: c++, linux, dlopen, dlsym

I am trying to load a .so file in my Qt application under Linux. That is working using the dlopen() and dlsym() for basic funcions. But I need to get multiple lists of string from the .so library, so I've tried to use a common .h file for both, but I can't access the object from the main app.

This is what I have so far:

**extmodule.h**

```
    #include <list>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    class ExtModule
    {
    public:
        ExtModule();

        list<string> L2MACSource;
        list<string> L2MACDest;
...
```

**modulefile.cpp**

```
#include "extmodule.h"
extern "C" ExtModule getCont() {
  ExtModule modul;
  modul.L2MACSource.push_back("...")
  return modul;
}
extern "C" void hello()
{
   cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "extmodule.h"
   ...
   dlopen("...../modulefile.so", RTLD_LAZY);
   ...
   typedef ExtModule(*loadedFunc)();
   loadedFunc ext_get = (loadedFunc)dlsym(ext_mod, "getCont");

   typedef void (*hello_t)();
   hello_t hello = (hello_t)dlsym(ext_mod, "hello");

   hello();
   ExtModule modul = ext_get();
```

hello() function works flawlessly, but I am not able to get the ext_get() working (/external.so: undefined symbol: _ZN9ExtModuleC1Ev). I have to retrieve multiple lists from the .so library, but I don't know if that is the correct way. Also, as you've probably guessed, I am not particularly skilled programmer. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You have not defined the ExtModule constructor.

Comment: And where and how it should be defined for it to work? Thank you :)

Comment: "where and how it should be defined for it to work". Do you know basics of C++? Do you know what a constructor is? Can you identify a constructor declaration in the posted code?

Comment: Yes, of course. I am a lame programmer, but not that lame :) I just didn't know where to implement it and if it requires some special configuration. Will update the original post with my findings. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You probably need to compile and link your main program with the `-rdynamic` flag (to ask the linker to emit dynamic symbols, so that names from the main program are visible to plugins) e.g.

```
 g++ -Wall -rdynamic -g main.cpp -o mainprog
```

<sup>perhaps some libraries and additional flags are missing above, e.g. for Qt</sup>

and your plugin with

```
 g++ -Wall -shared -g -fPIC modulefile.cpp -o module.so
```

<sup>perhaps also additional flags are missing above, e.g. for Qt</sup>

In practice, Qt knows about [plugins](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/plugins-howto.html) and `qmake` also has plugin support.

If using `dlopen` & `dlsym` you *always* should check for errors:

```
 ext_mod = dlopen("...../modulefile.so", RTLD_LAZY);
 if (!ext_mod) { 
   fprintf(stderr, "dlopen failure: %s\n", dlerror()); 
   exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

and also

```
 hello_t hello = (hello_t)dlsym(ext_mod, "hello");
 if (!hello) { 
   fprintf(stderr, "dlsym failure: %s\n", dlerror()); 
   exit (EXIT_FAILURE); }
```

Read [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html), [Program Library HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/), [C++ dlopen mini howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/), Drepper's paper: [How To write Shared Libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf), the [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book.

BTW, you don't show all of your C++ code. Please ensure that you have the required constructors and destructors. Read about the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29) (for old C++03) which becomes the rule of five in [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11).

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to generate your *.so file.

g++ -shared -fPIC -o {libname}.so -l{name of *.so file where definition of ExtModule} -L{path of module.}